# Android XML Resource Values Error

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

I am getting an error after modifying some of my xml resource files and I'm not quite sure how to fix it.

I was modifying my "main_activity.xml" layout file and went in to alter some text. Not wanting to hard code the values, I went in to create a "text style" by selecting my text, clicking "style" in the properties menu on the right hand page, then clicking the expand menu option to see all the available styles. This opened a "resources" dialog, these resources had resources like: "Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" and "Theme.AppCompat.Light" (I'll put a screenshot of the dialog box below)

[image: Resources Dialog]

I saw a "new style button" and attempted to create a couple of styles named things like "txtSize_28sp" with a value of 28sp for the text sizes. I do know that at one time I did create resource that had a name and no value, most likely with the: "txtSize_28sp" name. Problem is after doing this it has messed with my gradle build and I can no longer compile or run my project. The "R" in my R.layout.activity_main is no longer resolving and I keep getting this error message:

```
C:\Users\Ethan\Dropbox\Development\Android\Projects\DontTapTheAd\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\res\values\values.xml
Error:(380, 5) String types not allowed (at 'txtSize_28sp' with value '').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I have tried cleaning gradle, cleaning project, and syncing with gradle files. I can't find where to remove or fix my "txtSize_28sp" value.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a Find function in Android Studio that can search through the entire project files. Search for "txtSize_28sp" and ignore results in generated files (files created from building the project).

Comment: You could add your styles.xml file

Comment: Thanks for the replies. As far as using the "find function" I am not sure which one of the many find functions to use, I've tried pretty much all of them that I think would apply to be able to find the value. Like Anders said below I think it might be in one of the other API folders, which is why I can't find it. I'm not quite sure where to search for my different API values though. I don't really want to add my styles.xml file manually because I want to revert my IDE / SDK to the way it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple values for different APIs so check all the multiple folders of values for different APIs like value-21, it must be in one of the other APIs values folder.

Comment: I'm going to attempt to find the values in the different API's, do you have any suggestions on where and how to look at the different API folders?

Comment: well your `logcat` is telling you the problem is here `C:\Users\Ethan\Dropbox\Development\Android\Projects\DontTapTheAd\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\res\values\values.xml` so go to that directory and remove that line of code, if its not in that directory then you should check your `yourproject/app/main/res/allvaluesfolders`

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, I will try this and come back with the results. (I did already try the first directory and the code was not their so hopefully it will be in my main/res/allvalues folders.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ander who answered the question, after looking everywhere for these hidden lines of code and where they get added to the project I finally found them in the C:\Users\Ethan\Dropbox\Development\Android\Projects\AppName\app\src\main\res\values\dimens.xml file! Project was fixed after I removed the lines of code (such as: txtSize_28sp) in this file. (Screenshot of location where values were added in this post.)[image: Directory]